# Which system can one call "Embedded Linux based"?

Tags: linux, embedded

I am working on SBC(Single Board Computer) board with Red Hat Linux, which is being used to get information from many routers and process packets. 
Can this Gateway be called an "Embedded Linux based" product?

Answer (score 2):

I would call it embedded if its purpose has been shifted from a general purpose computer to a device or appliance that has a specific task. Further, customization for that specific task should probably remove/disable/mitigate some other general purpose functionality (e.g. running it headless, disabling/removing X or general use tools/services in order to further enable the device to do its job.)

Basically look at the device and discern whether it appears as "a computer running linux" or "an appliance which completes a specific task USING linux."

Answer (score 1):

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778800/whats-the-best-description-for-embedded-hardware-system) regarding which systems can be described as embedded. In industry terms, I would say that a headless Linux device is said to be "embedded".

Comment: What exactly you mean by headless. All the systems developed using SBCs can be called as embedded system.

Comment: SBCs are usually called embedded. A headless device is one without input/output, i.e. keyboard and monitor.

Comment: I could throw a bunch of headless servers, i.e. in a cluster, and I wouldn't call them "embedded"

Answer (score 1):

I don't agree that it needs to be headless to be considered embedded. For example, mobile phones are considered embedded but they've got video, i/o and what nots. Personally, I think that there is no 'clear' line for embedded. But generally, when you are working with minimal resources (e.g. minimal RAM) and performing very specific functions (i.e. not general purpose) then it's more embedded.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_system):

> An embedded system is a
>   special-purpose computer system
>   designed to perform one or a few
>   dedicated functions, often with
>   real-time computing constraints. It is
>   usually embedded as part of a complete
>   device including hardware and
>   mechanical parts. In contrast, a
>   general-purpose computer, such as a
>   personal computer, can do many
>   different tasks depending on
>   programming. Embedded systems control
>   many of the common devices in use
>   today.

While I think your device isn't embedded on another device, I see that has little functions and is not a general purpose computer.

Also, as Shashikiran says, SBCs are usually called embedded systems.

PC-104 drived me crazy some years ago...